# How to show $\frac{d}{d x}\left(|x|^{1/2}\right)=\frac{x}{2|x|^{3/2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

$$\frac{d}{d x}\left(|x|^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)=\frac{x}{2|x|^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

and also the second derivative $$\frac{d^{2}}{d x^{2}}\left(\sqrt{|x|}\right)=\frac{\delta(x)}{\sqrt{|x|}}-\frac{x^{2}}{4|x|^{\frac{7}{2}}}$$

I know this may seem basic. But I don't get how the Dirac delta (thanks for the comments for correcting me) comes in. Is it just a way someone has decided to write the result for $x >0$, $x<0$ and $x=0$ cleverly in one line. Is it arbitrary as long as the Kronecker term beats the other term?

If anyone has a clean derivation for these I'd be grateful.

EDIT: thanks for a lot of your answers, I've learnt a lot.
Still not entirely sure with the second derivative, the formula is here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second+derivative+of+%7Cx%7C%5E1%2F2, is this wrong? I still think it is probably correct. From taking something like. d/dx($\operatorname{sign}(x) \frac{1}{2|x|^{\frac{1}{2}}} )=1/2 ($$\frac{\delta(x)}{\sqrt{|x|}} -\frac{sign(x)*x}{2|x|^{5 / 2}})$ Don't know why first summand is missin 1/2. I know its distributions, but can't you still differentiate sign(x), you just have to be careful and when evaluating use test functions and integrals

Comment: Try writing $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$ and use the chain rule.

Comment: $\delta$ is not the Kronecker-delta here, but the Dirac-delta.

Comment: Ah yes ok how do you show with the dirac delta then.

Comment: Has anyone worked out the 2nd derivative?  I'm not getting it to match that at all.

Comment: Hmm I guess that as $[|x|^{\frac 12}]'$ and $x= 0$ will be "$\frac 1{0}$" it can be expressed in terms of the Dirac Delta function (although *precisely* how I'm too lazy to figure out).  So we taking the derivative of $\frac {x}{|x|^{\sqrt 32}}$ well taking into account $x$ might be $0$ the Dirac Dela function will play into account as some sort of product derivative:  First derivative is $[\int \delta(x)dx]\frac 1{|x|^{\frac 12}}$ so second derive is $\delta\frac 1{|x|^{\frac 12}} - [\frac 1{|x|^{\frac 12}}]'$.  Too lazy to work out the details....

Comment: This seems a very badly defined expression ... I will try to see if I can compute properly the second derivative in the sense of distributions

Comment: It seems that it should be $-\frac{\delta(x)}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ since $f''(x)\rightarrow-\infty$ as $x\rightarrow0$. So the be consistent you want the second derivative to reflect that.

Comment: I added a correct derivation. There is no Dirac delta involved in this derivative. I suppose the author tried to do an analogy with the case of the Coulomb potential where the Dirac delta appears?

Comment: In any event the use of $\delta$ here is misguided though. Dirac's $\delta$ is properly used in the so called theory of distributions. In the present setting, the term $\frac{\delta(x)}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ is not defined as a distribution.

Comment: Formula comes from here. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second+derivative+of+%7Cx%7C%5E1%2F2. Doesn't $f^{\prime \prime}(x) \rightarrow\infty$ as $x \rightarrow 0+$, I think the no minus sign may make sense.Not entirely sure if its a kosher formualtion

Comment: @JimSi: The problem with the formula is that the masterminds at wolfram in their infinite wisdom decided to codify the non existence of the second derivative of $x\mapsto \sqrt{|x|}$ at $x=0$ as $\delta(x)/\sqrt{|x|}$. The symbol $\delta$ in the context of derivatives has a special meaning in Mathematics, specially in the theory of distributions (or generalized functions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but for the case of the absolute function defined on the real numbers, this might help.

---

Since $|x|$ is non-differentiable only at $0$, all the derivatives we calculate will have domain $D \subseteq\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

If we write $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ we see that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left(|x| ^\frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{d}{dx} \left(x^2\right)^\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{4}\left(x^2\right)^{-\frac{3}{4}} \left[\frac{d}{dx}x^2 \right]= \frac{1}{4}\left(x^2\right)^{-\frac{3}{4}}2x = \frac{x}{2\left(x^2\right)^\frac{3}{4}}  = \frac{x}{2\left(\sqrt{x^2}\right)^\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{x}{2|x|^\frac{3}{2}}
$$
As for the second part
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} \left(|x| ^\frac{1}{2} \right) = \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{x}{2\left(x^2\right)^\frac{3}{4}}\right) = \frac{2\left(x^2\right)^\frac{3}{4} - 2x\left(\frac{3}{4}(x^2)^{-\frac{1}{4}} (2x)\right)}{4\left(x^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{2\left(x^2\right)^\frac{3}{4}}{4\left[\left(x^2\right)^\frac{3}{4}\right]^2} - \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\frac{4x^2}{4\left(x^2\right)^\frac{3}{2}(x^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}} = \frac{1}{2\left(x^2\right)^\frac{3}{4}}\left(\frac{2x^2}{2x^2}\right) - \frac{3x^2}{4\left(x^2\right)^\frac{7}{4}} =  \frac{2x^2 -3x^2} {4\left(x^2\right)^\frac{7}{4}} = -\frac{x^2}{4 |x|^\frac{7}{2}}
$$
Now, since the Dirac delta turns it's input into $0$ if $x \neq 0$, and the domain on which we're working on *doesn't* have $0$, our last answer will be equal to
$$
-\frac{x^2}{4 |x|^\frac{7}{2}} = 0 -\frac{x^2}{4 |x|^\frac{7}{2}} = \frac{\delta(x)}{\sqrt{|x|}} -\frac{x^2}{4 |x|^\frac{7}{2}}
$$
since $\frac{\delta(x)}{\sqrt{|x|}}=0$ for all $x \in D$.

I suspect there might be a more general definition of the absolute value you can work with to get the Dirac delta out directly, but I'm not familiar with it. Hope this helps!

Comment: "since δ(x)|x|√=0 for all x∈D"  well, that is *consistent*.... but it doesn't actually explain how or why the author derived the second derived with the Dirac Delta function in mind.  Do you have any idea what the author had in mind?

Comment: I don't know what the author had in mind. This is why I stated at the beginning that it wasn't a complete answer, I'm aware the answer doesn't *really* respond to the question. But I figured that I could "wiggle around" to get an answer in a form similar to the question's for the *particular case* of $x \neq 0$. 
However, my hope was that it would answer where *some* part of the answer came from, even though it didn't answer the main issue.

Comment: It is rather pedantic to have the $\delta$ there since the expression does not make in the sense of distributions and does not give any information about the behavior of the second derivative at $x=0$ other that it does not exists.

Comment: See my edit to the post:https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second+derivative+of+%7Cx%7C%5E1%2F2 formula is here. I think it comes from differentiate sign(x) directly. I'm not sure if it's legitamate. Or why there is no 1/2.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x) = |x|^{1/2}$. Of course, away from $x=0$, the answer of Robert Lee (without any Dirac delta) is correct, and you will just have
$$
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \frac{x}{2\,|x|^{3/2}}
\\
f''(x) &= \frac{-1}{4\,|x|^{3/2}}
\end{align*}
$$
for any $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ (since $x^2/|x|^{7/2} = 1/|x|^{3/2}$).

---

So, to know if there is a Dirac delta, you have to take the derivative in the sense of distributions. To get the first derivative, since $f'(x) = \frac{x}{2\,|x|^{3/2}}$
everywhere except at $x=0$, we see that $f'(x) = \frac{x}{2\,|x|^{3/2}}$ almost everywhere. Moreover, since $|f'| = \frac{1}{2\,|x|^{1/2}}$ is locally integrable, we obtain that the identity $f'(x) = \frac{x}{2\,|x|^{3/2}}$ is also valid locally in $L^1$ and so also in the sense of distributions.

This means that to compute $f''$ in the sense of distributions, we just need to compute the derivative of $f'$ in the sense of distributions. Let $\varphi$ be a smooth compactly supported (let say $\varphi = 0$ in $[-a,a]$ for some $a>0$) test function. Then by definition and the above computation
$$
\langle f'',\varphi\rangle = \langle(f')',\varphi\rangle = -\langle f',\varphi'\rangle = -\langle \tfrac{x}{2\,|x|^{3/2}},\varphi'\rangle
$$
and we can write this as an integral since both functions are locally integrable. Therefore
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle f'',\varphi\rangle &= -\int_{\mathbb{R}} \tfrac{x}{2\,|x|^{3/2}}\,\varphi'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = -\int_{-a}^a \tfrac{x}{2\,|x|^{3/2}}\,\varphi'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
\\
&= -\int_{-a}^a \tfrac{x}{2\,|x|^{3/2}}\,(\varphi(x)-\varphi(0))'\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
$$
Since $\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)$ is vanishing at $x=0$ and even better, $|\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)| ≤ C\,|x|$ (by the fundamental theorem of calculus, with $C= \sup |\varphi'|$ for instance), we can integrate by parts and use the value of $f''$ that was already computed for $x≠0$ to get
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle f'',\varphi\rangle &= \left[-\tfrac{x}{2\,|x|^{3/2}}\,(\varphi(x)-\varphi(0))\right]_{-a}^a - \int_{-a}^a \tfrac{1}{4\,|x|^{3/2}}\,(\varphi(x)-\varphi(0))\,\mathrm{d}x
\\
&= - \int_{-a}^a \tfrac{1}{4\,|x|^{3/2}}\,(\varphi(x)-\varphi(0))\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
$$
since $\varphi(a) = \varphi(-a) = 0$. The distribution $\mathrm{pf}(\frac{1}{|x|^a})$ for $a\in(1,2)$ is known as the finite part of $\frac{1}{|x|^a}$ and is defined exactly by
$$
\begin{align*}
\langle \mathrm{pf}(\tfrac{1}{|x|^a}),\varphi\rangle &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \tfrac{1}{|x|^{a}}\,(\varphi(x)-\varphi(0))\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
$$
so in the sense of distributions
$$
f'' = \frac{-1}{4} \mathrm{pf}\left(\frac{1}{|x|^{3/2}}\right)
$$

---

**Remarks:** I do not know where you found the formula with a Dirac delta but it is obviously wrong, since there is no meaning to $\frac{\delta(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Even if it is true that $\mathrm{sign}' = \delta_0$ in the sense of distributions, the following computation
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{x}{|x|^{3/2}}\right) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\mathrm{sign}(x)\frac{1}{|x|^{1/2}}\right) = 2\delta_0(x)\left(\frac{1}{|x|^{1/2}}\right) + \mathrm{sign}(x)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{1}{|x|^{1/2}}\right)
$$
**is not valid** since one cannot multiply singular distributions in general.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second+derivative+of+%7Cx%7C%5E1%2F2. You think this is wrong. Maybe it just does d/x($\operatorname{sign}(x) \frac{1}{2|x|^{\frac{1}{2}}} =1/2 ($$\frac{\delta(x)}{\sqrt{|x|}} -\frac{sign(x)*x}{2|x|^{5 / 2}})$ Don't know why first summand is missin 1/2. I know its distributions, but can't you still differentiate sign(x) like that, and evaluate llike you have with interals

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will work through it as it seems a good exercise. I need to refresh about distributioins, and test fns.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot define the product of $\delta_0$ with $1/\sqrt{|x|}$ in a consistant way. A common way to see why one should be careful about multiplying distributions is to look at $H = \mathbf{1}_{x>0}$ and since $H' = \delta_0$ and $H^n=H$ we have for example
$$
\delta_0 = H' = (H^n)' = n H^{n-1} H' = n H^{n-1} \delta_0 = n H \delta_0
$$
and using this formula for example for $n=2$ and $n=3$ we get
$$
\delta_0 = 2 H \delta_0 = 3 H \delta_0
$$
so
$$
\frac{1}{2}\delta_0 = \frac{1}{3}\delta_0
$$
so
$$
\delta_0 = 0
$$
and you can integrate it to get $1=0$.

Comment: The error was exactly at the step when I use the chain rule, since $H\delta_0$ is not well defined. You can only multiply $\delta_0$ by functions $f$ that are continuous in $0$, and then you have $\delta_0 f = f(0)$.

Yeah, it is very strange to see that in Wolfram Alpha ...

Comment: Actually, you can prove $1=0$ with Wolfram Alpha  using this kind of reasoning

Comment: Ok perfect. Thanks a lot. Odd that wolfram alpha does this.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt{\pm x}\to\pm\frac1{2\sqrt{\pm x}}$$ so

$$\sqrt{|x|}\to\text{sgn}(x)\frac1{2\sqrt{|x|}}.$$

For the second derivative, you can use the same method. But as there is a discontinuity, you can represent its derivative with a $\delta$.

Answer (score 2):

You may split your function $f(x):=|x|^{1/2}$ on whether $x\geq0$ or $x<0$. If the former case,
you have
$$\frac{d}{dx} (x^{1/2})=\frac12 x^{-1/2}=\frac12\frac{x}{x^{3/2}}=\frac12\frac{x}{|x|^{3/2}}
$$
In the later
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\big((-x)^{1/2}\big) = -\frac12\big((-x)^{-1/2}\big)=-\frac12 |x|^{1/2}=-\frac12\frac{|x|}{|x|^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{|x|^{3/2}}
$$

For the second order integral you may proceed in a similar manner. It may be helpful to notice that  notice that the first derivative is discontinuous at $x=0$ (division by $0$ kind of thing).

For $x>0$,
$$f''(x) = -\frac14 x^{-3/2}=-\frac14\frac{x^2}{|x|^{7/2}}$$
For $x<0$ $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2}\big((-x)^{-1/2}\big)$ and so,
$$f''(x)=-\frac{1}{4}(-x)^{-3/2} = -\frac14\frac{x^2}{|x|^{7/2}}$$

At $x=0$, $f''$ is not defined, but $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f''(x)=-\infty$.So to reflect that (in a rather pedantic way) one may write

$f''(x)=-\frac{\delta(x)}{|x|^{1/2}}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{x^2}{|x|^{7/2}}$

Here $\delta(x)=1$ if $x=0$ and $\delta(x)=0$ otherwise. Any constant factor in the $\delta$ will produce the idea that $f''$ is not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: Ok so for x ≠ 0, $\frac{d^{2}}{d x^{2}}(\sqrt{|x|})=-\frac{x^{2}}{4|x|^{7 / 2}}$ right? and when x =0, +ve infinity essentially?, because it's divided by minimum amount to boost going to infinity to beat $-\frac{x^{2}}{4|x|^{7 / 2}}$'s neg infinity pace. Sorry for the really bad terminology

Comment: The use of $\delta$ here is misguided though. Dirac's $\delta$ is properly used in the so called theory of distributions. In the present setting, the term $\frac{\delta(x)}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ is not defined as a distribution.

Comment: (+1) For apparently being the only person on this page stating that $\delta(x)$ is **not** a function. I find it shortsighted for anyone to spread that misconception. $\delta$ doesn't even come into the question unless we are asking about a functional derivative - there is no "ordinary" derivative of $\sqrt{|x|}$ at $0$ because it doesn't exist there.

Answer (score 2):

According to my calculations the correct answer is
$$
(|x|^{1/2})''
= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( - \epsilon^{-1/2} \, \delta(x) + \frac14 (1-\chi_{(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}(x)) |x|^{-3/2} \right)
$$

Calculation (sorry for lack of comments):
$$\begin{align}
\langle |x|_+^{1/2}, \varphi(x) \rangle &:= \int_0^\infty x^{1/2} \, \varphi(x) \, dx
= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^\infty x^{1/2} \, \varphi(x) \, dx \\
\langle |x|_-^{1/2}, \varphi(x) \rangle &:= \int_{-\infty}^0 (-x)^{1/2} \, \varphi(x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty x^{1/2} \, \varphi(-x) \, dx = \langle |x|_+^{1/2}, \varphi(-x) \rangle \\
%\langle |x|^{1/2}, \varphi(x) \rangle &:= \langle |x|_+^{1/2}, \varphi(x) \rangle + \langle |x|_-^{1/2}, \varphi(x) \rangle \\
|x|^{1/2} &:= |x|_+^{1/2} + |x|_-^{1/2}
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\langle D|x|_+^{1/2}, \varphi(x) \rangle
&= -\langle |x|_+^{1/2}, \varphi'(x) \rangle \\
&= -\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^\infty x^{1/2} \, \varphi'(x) \, dx \\
&= -\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( \left[ x^{1/2} \, \varphi(x) \right]_\epsilon^\infty - \int_\epsilon^\infty \frac12 x^{-1/2} \, \varphi(x) \, dx \right) \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( \epsilon^{1/2} \, \varphi(\epsilon) + \int_\epsilon^\infty \frac12 x^{-1/2} \, \varphi(x) \, dx \right) \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  \int_\epsilon^\infty \frac12 x^{-1/2} \, \varphi(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^\infty \frac12 x^{-1/2} \, \varphi(x) \, dx \\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\langle D^2|x|_+^{1/2}, \varphi(x) \rangle
&= -\langle D|x|_+^{1/2}, \varphi'(x) \rangle \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^\infty \frac12 x^{-1/2} \, \varphi'(x) \, dx \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( \left[ \frac12 x^{-1/2} \, \varphi(x) \right]_\epsilon^\infty - \int_\epsilon^\infty (-\frac14) x^{-3/2} \, \varphi(x) \, dx \right) \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( -\frac12 \epsilon^{-1/2} \, \varphi(\epsilon) + \frac14 \int_\epsilon^\infty x^{-3/2} \, \varphi(x) \, dx \right) \\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\langle D^2|x|_-^{1/2}, \varphi(x) \rangle
&= \langle |x|_-^{1/2}, \varphi''(x) \rangle \\
&= \langle |x|_+^{1/2}, \varphi''(-x) \rangle \\
&= \langle |x|_+^{1/2}, D^2\left(\varphi(-x)\right) \rangle \\
&= \langle D^2|x|_+^{1/2}, \varphi(-x) \rangle \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( -\frac12 \epsilon^{-1/2} \, \varphi(-\epsilon) + \frac14 \int_\epsilon^\infty x^{-3/2} \, \varphi(-x) \, dx \right) \\
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
\langle D^2|x|^{1/2}, \varphi(x) \rangle
&= \langle D^2|x|_+^{1/2}, \varphi(x) \rangle + \langle D^2|x|_-^{1/2}, \varphi(x) \rangle \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( -\frac12 \epsilon^{-1/2} \, \varphi(\epsilon) + \frac14 \int_\epsilon^\infty x^{-3/2} \, \varphi(x) \, dx \right) \\
&+ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( -\frac12 \epsilon^{-1/2} \, \varphi(-\epsilon) + \frac14 \int_\epsilon^\infty x^{-3/2} \, \varphi(-x) \, dx \right) \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( -\frac12 \epsilon^{-1/2} \, \left(\varphi(\epsilon)+\varphi(-\epsilon)\right) + \frac14 \int_\epsilon^\infty x^{-3/2} \, \left(\varphi(x)+\varphi(-x)\right) \, dx \right) \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( - \epsilon^{-1/2} \, \varphi(0) + \frac14 \int_{|x|>\epsilon} |x|^{-3/2} \, \varphi(x) \, dx \right) \\
&= \langle \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \left( - \epsilon^{-1/2} \, \delta(x) + \frac14 (1-\chi_{(-\epsilon,\epsilon)}(x)) |x|^{-3/2} \right), \varphi(x) \rangle \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is the derivative in the sense of distributions. It coincides with the classical derivative on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

**First Derivative**

For real $x$,
$$
|x|^2=x^2\tag1
$$
so that
$$
2|x|\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}|x|=2x\tag2
$$
Therefore, away from $0$, we have
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}|x|=\frac{x}{|x|}\tag3
$$
The chain rule then says
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}|x|^{1/2}
&=\frac12|x|^{-1/2}\frac{x}{|x|}\tag{4a}\\
&=\frac12\frac{x}{|x|^{3/2}}\tag{4b}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Second Derivative**

Approximating $|x|^{1/2}\approx\left(\epsilon^2+x^2\right)^{1/4}$, we get
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}\left(\epsilon^2+x^2\right)^{1/4}
=\frac{3\epsilon^2-\left(\epsilon^2+x^2\right)}{4\left(\epsilon^2+x^2\right)^{7/4}}\tag5
$$
Consider
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\,\frac{3\epsilon^2-\left(\epsilon^2+x^2\right)}{4\left(\epsilon^2+x^2\right)^{7/4}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{|x|\ge\epsilon^{2/3}} f(x)\,\frac{3\epsilon^2-\left(\epsilon^2+x^2\right)}{4\left(\epsilon^2+x^2\right)^{7/4}}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{6a}\\
&+\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{|x|\lt\epsilon^{2/3}} f(x)\,\frac{3\epsilon^2-\left(\epsilon^2+x^2\right)}{4\left(\epsilon^2+x^2\right)^{7/4}}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{6b}\\
&=-\frac14\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\,|x|^{-3/2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{6c}\\[3pt]
&+\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{|x|\lt\epsilon^{-1/3}} f(\epsilon x)\,\frac{3-\left(1+x^2\right)}{4\left(1+x^2\right)^{7/4}}\,\epsilon^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{6d}
\end{align}
$$
Note that for the integral in $\text{(6c)}$ to converge, we must have $f(0)=0$.

Let's look at the size of the integral in $\text{(6d)}$. Since $\frac{3-\left(1+x^2\right)}{4\left(1+x^2\right)^{7/4}}$ is even, we only need to worry about the even part of $f$, which is bounded by $cx^2$ near $x=0$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{|x|\lt\epsilon^{-1/3}} c(\epsilon x)^2\,\frac{3-\left(1+x^2\right)}{4\left(1+x^2\right)^{7/4}}\,\epsilon^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}x\right|
&\le\left.\frac{c}4\epsilon^2|x|^3\epsilon^{-1/2}\right|_{-\epsilon^{-1/3}}^{+\epsilon^{-1/3}}\tag{7a}\\
&=\frac{c}2\epsilon^2\epsilon^{-1}\epsilon^{-1/2}\tag{7b}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{c}2\epsilon^{1/2}\tag{7c}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, under the condition that $f(0)=0$,
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\,\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}x^2}\sqrt{|x|}\,\mathrm{d}x
=-\frac14\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\,|x|^{-3/2}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag8
$$

Comment: As a comment, this doesn't give an explicit formula for the distributional second derivative $(|x|^{1/2})''$, since the action of $(|x|^{1/2})''$ on $f$ has been specified only for some test functions $f$.

Answer (score -1):

A good way is to use Einstein summation notation. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)

Using $x^2 = x_ix_i$, we have

$$(\frac{d}{dx}|x|^{1/2})_j = \frac{d}{dx_j}(x_ix_i)^{1/4} = \frac{1}{4}(x_ix_i)^{-3/4}(\delta_{ij}x_i + x_i \delta_{ij}) = \frac{x_j}{2(x_ix_i)^{3/4}}$$.

Comment: Can the downvoter please clarify what I did was wrong?

Comment: IMO, this obscures the question rather than answer it and uses concepts unkown of the OP.

Comment: @YvesDaoust alright. Fair point. Now I don't know how to proceed with the second derivative.

Comment: Ah ok thanks a lot, I do understand that. Haven't done maths in a while.

Answer (score -2):

Okay.... second go.....

If $1 =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) dx$ then if we have a function $f(x)$ where $f(x)$ "equals $\frac 10$" when $x=0$  I *guess* can say:

$f(x) = 1*f(x) = [\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) dx]f(x)$ so

$f'(x)= [\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) dx]'f(x) + [\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) dx]f(x)= \delta(x)f(x) + f'(x)$.

When $x\ne 0$ then this is $f'(x)$.  If $x=0$ then... well I'm waving my hands wildly... but as $f(x)$ is assymptotic at $x=0$ then the derivative is infinite.

So.... $|x|^{\frac 12}$ is defined everywhere but has a "divot" at $x=0$.

the first derivative if $sign(x) \frac 1{2|x|^{\frac 12}} = \frac x{2|x|^{\frac 32}}$.

Not the first derivative "equals $\frac 10$ at $x = 0$ so if we take that the first derivative is $[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) dx]\cdot\frac x{2|x|^{\frac 32}}$ then the second derivative will be $\delta(x)sign(x) \frac 1{2|x|^{\frac 12}} + [sign(x) \frac 1{2|x|^{\frac 12}}]'=$

$\pm \delta(x)sign(x) \frac 1{2|x|^{\frac 12}} -\frac{x^{2}}{4|x|^{\frac{7}{2}}}$

.....

Okay, somehow in my not really knowing what I was doing and handwaving I handwaved $\frac {sign(x)}2$ in whereas the author doing whatever s/he was doing and knowing what she was doing probably had a reason they "canceled" out.

Actually, I think I can *almost* see why.  $\operatorname{sign}(x) \frac 1{2|x|^{\frac 12}} = \frac x{2|x|^{\frac 32}}$ is negative of $x < 0$ and positive otherwise so so we don't really have the first derivative of $[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) dx]\cdot\frac x{2|x|^{\frac 32}}$ but the $sign(x)[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x) dx]\cdot\frac x{2|x|^{\frac 32}}$ and so the signs cancel out. And as we are doing it for negative and positive values of $x$ we ... are doing it twice????  Okay.... I'm handwaving again.

....

I *don't* know what the author was doing but I can see that as the first derivative is infinite at $x=0$ and as $\delta(x) =0$ whe $x \ne 0$ so the result is consistant and that weird chain rule for differentiating $f(x)_{x\ne 0}= 1 = \int \delta(x)dx$ I can squint and *almost* see what the author had in mind.